# iPhone 5 not charging via USB from PC

Tags: usb, charging, iphone, pc

I charge my phone using my PC all the time, and it's been only a week that since I bought my iPhone 5. Now I can't charge my phone with my PC.

What could be the problem thats causing my phone to not charge while connected to my PC?

The USB charger is new.

Comment: Is iTunes still picking up the iPhone?

Comment: Are you saying it's never worked, or that it worked when it was new, and now does not?

Comment: What USB charger - if from the PC then a direct USB leans and no charger

Comment: Feel free to edit in details of the PC like whether iTunes sees the phone and we can evaluate if this isn't a duplicate of other questions on the same general topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inside of the phone's charger port with a flashlight. Lint can block all the pins from making a connection which will cause the phone not to charge. Same goes for any open connections like the DC "cigarette lighter" port. Try cleaning the hole(s) out I guess is what I'm saying

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean usb charging cable. there could be a couple of things.

1. The new cable you got is not supported by apple. The lightning chargers contain a specialized chip, if the vendor is not apple authorized, it probably wont let it charge.
2. The new cable , doesn't provide proper charge. It may be faulty/provide lesser power than required to charge the phone.

If you can return it, do that. If you cannot, then try charging it using wall charging point which came  with the new iPhone. and see if the new cable works there.